# Is Zero ring a Boolean ring?

Tags: boolean-ring

I have a simple doubt. Is zero ring a Boolean ring? ( We do have $0 ^2 =0$ ). Or do we assume a Boolean ring to be non-zero?. The doubt came in my mind while showing that in a Boolean ring every prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: Is the one-point Boolean algebra a Boolean algebra?

Comment: Sorry, but till now I haven't encountered with the definition of Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement that a Boolean ring have more than one element. (Contrast this with [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), where we explicitly require that the additive and multiplicative identities be distinct). So yes, the trivial ring is a Boolean ring.

---

Re: your edit, note that "prime = maximal" is (appropriately enough) trivially true for the trivial Boolean ring: both prime and maximal ideals are required to be nonempty *proper* subsets of the ring itself, and the trivial Boolean ring has no nonempty proper subsets at all.

(Actually, it looks like there's a subtlety here: being a proper subset of the ring is not included in the wikipedia definition of prime ideals in [the context of *noncommutative* rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_noncommutative_rings). I suspect that this is an omission on wikipedia's part, but if not then "prime = maximal" using this notion of "prime ideal" does indeed fail for the trivial ring.)

Comment: Thank you but is not the zero ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ a prime ideal?

Comment: @MohitSharma What is "$\mathbb{Z}$" here? (Note that that symbol usually denotes the integers, which do **not** form a Boolean ring.)

Comment: If by "$\mathbb{Z}$" you mean the trivial ring, then **no**, the zero ideal is not prime in the trivial ring since - as I say in my answer - the zero ideal is not a **proper** subset of the trivial ring.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I understood. The zero ideal is not a proper subset of the zero ring and the definition of prime ideal requires it to be a proper subset of the ring.

Comment: Sorry i asked about the zero ideal being prime in $\mathbb{Z} $ because in your answer I read non-empty to be non-zero. My mistake!.